# Como usar GetSetting/SaveSetting em Windows Services

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, services

Criei um serviço e configurei-o como *LocalSystem*.

Na implementação eu tento buscar um registro salvo no `REGEDIT` por outro programa. O método 
`GetSetting` sempre me retorna vazio. Existe alguma forma de recuperar/salvar dados no `REGEDIT` utilizando Windows Services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está cedendo a [permissão de leitura](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.security.permissions.registrypermission?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) como a [**função**](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.getsetting?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframework-4.8#Microsoft_VisualBasic_Interaction_GetSetting_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_) requer? Se preferir um outro modo de obter e alterar esses dados, você pode utilizar os métodos da classe [`RegistryKey`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) para isso.

Para recuperar um valor você pode usar o método [`GetValue()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvalue?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Win32_RegistryKey_GetValue_System_String_).

```
const string REG_KEY_NAME = @"SOFTWARE\Bar\Baz";
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(REG_KEY_NAME, false)) // Abrir a key para leitura
{
    string Valor = key.GetValue("NomeDoValor").ToString();
}
```

Para alterar um valor ou os dados, poderá usar o método [`SetValue()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.setvalue?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#Microsoft_Win32_RegistryKey_SetValue_System_String_System_Object_).

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(REG_KEY_NAME, true)) // Abrir a key para leitura/gravação
{
    key.SetValue("NomeDoValor", "FooBar");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/Registry.cs).

Answer (score 2):

O que você deseja normalmente é obtido através da classe [`Registry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx).Algo assim:

```
Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Chave", "ChaveEspecifica", 0)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/RegistryGetValue.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi o meu problema utilizando um arquivo `XML` para armazenar os dados que eu irei utilizar posteriormente.

Certamente não é a melhor forma, mas como meu `serviço` está como `LocalSystem` e tem permissões de Usuário de Serviço então eu não posso ter acesso aos registros do `CurrentUser`, sendo assim não posso obter os valores.